# Convert IPv4 packet to IPv6

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I am modifying kernel module (called map) in vyatta to convert IPv4 packet to IPv6.

http://enog.jp/~masakazu/vyatta/map/

I could do the conversation by removing the IPv4 header and and adding new IPv6 header, but after I call `ip6_local_out()`, it returns no error, but the packet is still in the struct sk_buff skb I am using. When I use tcpdump I can not see the new IPv6 packet. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

```
skb_dst_drop(skb);
skb_dst_set(skb, dst);

memcpy(&orig_iph, iph, sizeof(orig_iph));
skb_pull(skb, orig_iph.ihl * 4);
skb_push(skb, sizeof(struct ipv6hdr));
skb_reset_network_header(skb);
skb->protocol = htons(ETH_P_IPV6);
ipv6h = ipv6_hdr(skb);

ipv6h->version = 6;
ipv6h->priority = 0; /* XXX: */
ipv6h->flow_lbl[0] = 0;
ipv6h->flow_lbl[1] = 0;
ipv6h->flow_lbl[2] = 0;
ipv6h->payload_len = htons(ntohs(orig_iph.tot_len) - orig_iph.ihl * 4);
ipv6h->hop_limit = orig_iph.ttl;
memcpy(&ipv6h->saddr, &fl6.saddr, sizeof(struct in6_addr));

ipv6h->nexthdr = orig_iph.protocol;

pkt_len = skb->len;

skb->local_df = 1;

if (df)
    err = ip6_local_out(skb);
else
    err = ip6_fragment(skb, ip6_local_out);

return 0;
```

I use a my method called `map_debug_print_skb("map_trans_forward_v4v6", skb);` which prints IP header and transport header. I could see all the new IPv6 header detail from it but the packet is not showing in tcpdump.

Comment: If you have IPv64 packets I think you need to step back in your Tardis...

Comment: First problem I can tell you is that if you are dealing with IP datagrams carrying TCP payload you have to recalculate the TCP checksum. That could be one problem.